# GraphQL: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo, react-apollo

I have an Apollo GraphQL projects where I have created my own Query and Mutations. I have done using mock data and Query and Mutation works fine. But when I am trying to do with Sequelize ORM, I am getting the error

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getListings' of undefined",
            "    at listings (/home/ayman/Desktop/apollo-graphql/graphql-app/functions/graphql.js:50:19)",
            "    at field.resolve (/home/ayman/Desktop/apollo-graphql/graphql-app/node_modules/graphql-extensions/dist/index.js:134:26)"
```

Query and Mutations in `graphql.js`:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql} = require("apollo-server-lambda");
const { Listing, User } = require("../db");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    listings: [Listing!]!
  }
  type Mutation {
    createListing(input: CreateListingInput!): Listing!
  }
  input CreateListingInput {
    title: String!
    description: String
    url: String!
    notes: String
  }
  type Contact {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    company: Company
    email: String
    notes: String
  }
  type Company {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    logo: String
    listings: [Listing!]!
    url: String
  }
  type Listing {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String
    url: String!
    notes: String
    company: Company
    contacts: [Contact!]!
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    listings(_, __, { user }) {
      return user.getListings();
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    createListing(_, { input }, { user }) {
      return Listing.create({ ...input, userId: user.id });
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

exports.handler = server.createHandler();
```

I have Sequilize along with Postgres database:

`db.js`

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING, {
  dialect: "pg",
  dialectModule: require('pg'),
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: true,
  },
});

class User extends Sequelize.Model {}
User.init(
  {
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "user",
  }
);

class Listing extends Sequelize.Model {}
Listing.init(
  {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    url: Sequelize.STRING,
    notes: Sequelize.TEXT,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "listing",
  }
);

Listing.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Listing);

exports.sequelize = sequelize;
exports.User = User;
exports.Listing = Listing;
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/AymanArif/graphql-app/tree/AuthN-Refactor)

1. Run using `netlify dev`
2. Go to URL: http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/graphql
3. Sample GraphQL query

```
{
 listings {
     id
     title
     description
     url
     company {
        name
        url
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating your `context` object?

Comment: I am using `user` from `db.js` as part of Apollo's [resolver](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use the third argument of the resolver, which is `context` - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-arguments, but you're never adding a `context` initialization function to the `ApolloServer` constructor.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
return user.getListings();
```

you probably mean User, because user is undefined

Comment: Tried it but gives same error.
`return user.getListings();` comes under custom Apollo Resolver to fetch details from datasources.

Answer (score 0):

I see,  you are trying to access user object from context. Please check the context definition. It should return an object containing user object explicitly.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Please check the code where the Apollo server is confugured. Context is passed as a key to apollo server configuration.